# Inference variable T has incompatible bounds with specific Class<T> and instance <T> in one method

Tags: java, generics, extends

I'm using library which contains method I want to use. Simplified signature would look like this:

```
final class ThirdPartyClass
{
    public static <T> void thirdPartyMethod(Class<T> clazz, T instance)
    {
        // does something
    }
}
```

Inside `thirdPartyMethod()` it expects **class** of `T` as first argument and an **instance** of that specific class `T` as second argument.

Now I have this simple abstract class, which is calling that method:

```
abstract class Parent<T extends Number>
{
    public Parent(T instance)
    {
        ThirdPartyClass.thirdPartyMethod(instance.getClass(), instance);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> method thirdPartyMethod in class ThirdPartyClass cannot be applied to given types;
> required: java.lang.Class, T
> found:    java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Number>, T
> reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
> equality constraints: capture#2 of ? extends java.lang.Number
> lower bounds: T

How can I modify the `Parent` class so it conforms to expected arguments of `thirdPartyMethod()`?
If possible with explanation.

Comment: you can declare `Class<? extends T> clazz` as, T is inferred as compile time, but the actual class will be known at runtime (basically `instance` can be `Number instance = new Integer(5);`

Comment: @njzk2 I'm afraid I cannot modify `thirdPartyMethod()` signature as it comes from library I'm using.

Comment: I would just cast `(Class<T>)instance.getClass()`.

Comment: @tgdavies That indeed works! It just produces pesky warning about unchecked cast, but I can suppress that I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the return type of [`Object.getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())

> The actual result type is `Class<? extends |X|>` where `|X|` is the
> erasure of the static type of the expression on which getClass is
> called.

Since `T` extends `Number`, the resulting type would be `Class<? extends Number>`, i.e. means an *unknown type* extending `Number`. Which doesn't match `T extends Number` (i.e. a *particular* type extending `Number` which would be provided at runtime).

> How can I modify the Parent class so it conforms to expected arguments of thirdPartyMethod()?

**1.** Introduce a second parameter of type `Class<T>` in your constructor.

```
abstract class Parent<T extends Number> {
    public Parent(T instance, Class<T> tClass) {
        ThirdPartyClass.thirdPartyMethod(tClass, instance);
    }
}
```

**2.** Perform casting (as have been mentioned in the comments):

```
ThirdPartyClass.thirdPartyMethod((Class<T>) instance.getClass(), instance);
```

By the way, instead of calling methods from a constructor (especially ones that are not developed and tested by you/your colleagues) you might consider introducing a factory method that would produce your domain object based on the result of a method call.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer with explanation. It makes sense to me now. I have chosen the first way - introducing second parameter.